# php website auto redirect 404 error page if there is get parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my website when I pass any data by get method, it is redirecting to 404.html.

For example,
in http://www.exaple.com/enquiry.html?id=2 is redirecting to error code 404.

but
http://www.exaple.com/enquiry.html
is working.

Please suggest because there is no issue in httaccess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We cannot guess your urls, htaccess and redirect method. Can you give us a code snippet?

Comment: Could it be that HTML pages don't allow parameters to be stored within them? Or that you've spelled 'example' incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks peter for quick response, I am working on php based website. When I pass data by "get" method. File auto redirecting to not found page.

Comment: Hi Lee, exaple is just example only. Sorry for misspelling. Html page allow parameter. This website is working fine in local system

Comment: Please try following url: http://classictajtours.com/enquiry-now.html?id=49  and http://classictajtours.com/enquiry-now.html

Comment: @AmitJha: I am getting redirect loop for `http://classictajtours.com/enquiry-now.html?id=49`. Can you show your current rules in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Requests for

```
http://classictajtours.com/enquiry-now.html?id=49
```

are 301 redirecting to

```
http://www.classictajtours.com/http://www.classictajtours.com/enquiry-now.html
```

which continues to redirect back to itself in a redirect loop.  I'd take a look in your HTTP server config files for the error.